# Facebook Graph Search Error while searching "Event"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is embarrassing, but I am at my wits end. While performing a very simple search for "Events" using fb Graph Search, I get the following error:

```
 {
  "error": {
  "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 200
}}
```

This is the code I execute:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event&limit=1&access_token=XXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXX
```

It works JUST FINE for any other type of search - with the same access token for example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=place&limit=1&access_token=XXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXX
```

I get the following result:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "category": "Local business",
     "category_list": [
        {
           "id": "164243073639257",
           "name": "Hotel"
        }
     ],
     "location": {
        "street": "Langelaan 3",
        "city": "Noordwijk",
        "state": "",
        "country": "Netherlands",
        "zip": "2211XT",
        "latitude": 52.251963727407,
        "longitude": 4.4722281054509
     },
     "name": "NH Conference Centre Leeuwenhorst",
     "id": "165032770219308"
  }
],
  "paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=1&type=place&access_token=XXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX&offset=1&__after_id=165032770219308"
}
}
```

At this point, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook recently changed things in their API, Search was one of those things. You can only do this kind of search on Places and Pages now. To search events, you need an app access token. See this blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: Thanks much for your response; I noticed that the app access token I am passing in my example is actually my 'app id + "|" + app secret'. I guess that brings me back to square one...

Comment: Before I go any further, I am going to verify if I have the latest versions of the fb SDK.

Comment: Fixed! I am now able to search for events by using an App Token generated using the new api. Thank everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I am now able to search for events by using an App Token generated using the new api. Thank everyone for your help